# Error detection Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just downloaded **visual studio 2010 professional** and was surprised that error correction does not seem to work. I have already checked under

Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> C/C++ -> Advanced but everything seems ok. Error detection disabled is set to FALSE.

I want VS to autodetect error - in the same way as misspellings are detected in Eclipse
For instance

```
  cout // get error notification if I omitt the namespace std
  cour // oups, wrong keystroke. Underline immediately
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to hit F5 or Build project. VS2010 is very sluggish sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to re-build the entire solution sometimes.  I've noticed that occasionally, Visual Studio can end up with corrupt debug files.  Re-building the entire solution usually fixes the corrupt files.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild whole solution. VS 2010 is not very good release of that IDE. I suggest migrating to VS 2012 or VS 2013.